# .NET Project Namespace Hell

Tags: c#, namespaces, visual-studio-2005

I have a Visual Studio 2005 project with 327 errors "The type name '_xsd' does not exist in the type 'TR.TR'."

This project is supposed to be a duplicate of a project I have on another machine so I don't want them to be inconsistent. My other project compiles just fine with the same default namespace and the same namespace specified in the source files. I cannot figure out why this project is unable to resolve its namespace. These projects should be identical.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the project is referencing files that either were not copied (it's possible to reference things that are not inside the project's directory) or the file did get copied but the references to them don't work because you've changed the file path.

Visual Studio isn't very transparent about these references. There should be a "Solution Explorer" window on the right side of Visual Studio. If you right click you can add references to files. I'd try adding references to the files it says don't exist.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem. There was a **TR.resx** file which seems to have been causing all the problems. I noticed this file was not in my original project. When I deleted it the project compiled with no errors.